# mySQL query. ORDER BY  meta_key

Tags: query, post-meta, mysql, order

I'm fighting this quite long already and start to think I'm missing something big. CPT posts could have or not metadata ( `_vip_post [0|1]`, `_thumbnail_id [null|numeric]` ).

If i query for `_thumbnail_id` it's ok and works:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON ( wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
ORDER BY 
    m.meta_key DESC,
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Returns posts with thumbnails first, `_thumbnail_id` = null comes last. good enough for now. Working.

But if I query for my new `_vip_post` meta_key It's totally ignored in ordering. Same pattern.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON ( wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = '_vip_post')
ORDER BY 
    m.meta_key DESC,
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Just ordered by `post_date`. Not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zlatev

**meta_key** is the name of the custom post type, and is a VARCHAR(255)
**meta_value** is the value of the key, and is a longtext

With your query you are not ordering by values, but by the name of the field. The query works for _thumbnail_id because you are using LEFT JOIN and the CPT could be null.

You could see if you run this query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* ,m.*
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON ( wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
ORDER BY 
    m.meta_key ASC,
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

See the null for the meta_key

In the second case, the CPT _vip_post IS always present, so the ordering on the fieldname is not working. You must order it by meta_value.

Try something like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* ,m.*
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON ( wp_posts.ID = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = '_vip_post')
ORDER BY 
    m.meta_value ASC,
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

You can change the ordering by using *m.meta_value DESC*.

Comment: omg. so ashamed but it worked.